# in yii2, yii\grid\ActionColumn class giving empty column at all tables in a database

Tags: yii2

I am using gridview , It is showing action column empty. it is not showing icon for edit, delete, view. can any one tell what is problem??
here is code

```
<?php
                $gridColumns = [
                [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                ],
                'id',
                'name',
                'created',
                'modified',
                'modified_by_id',
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],                
            ]; ?>
        <?php
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'columnSelectorMenuOptions' => 
        [
            'style'=> 'overflow-y: scroll, height: auto; 
                       max-height: 300px;  overflow-x: hidden;', 
       ],
        'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_SELF ,
          ]); 

        ?>
        <?php 
        echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        ]); 
        ?>
```

Comment: where you can't see the grid view  .. in ExportMenu or in GridView  .. ?

Comment: It is showing gridview, but action column is empty..

Comment: Looks right to me, if you are using the default ActionColumn class with default settings (especially for 'template'). Are you?

Comment: am new to yii2.. i did not use any template.. only export menu and grid view.. previously befor adding export menu it was working fine... but now showing action column empty and search is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution...In vendor folder actioncolumn.php file a line was commented ..thats why it Was showing blank column

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
         'template' => '{delete}',
        ]
```

the "delete" should be your action name in the controller.

Comment: thank you so much... but it was my silly mistake.. dont know how but in actioncolumn.php in vendor folder a line was commented...